# How do i move <a> with <background> in <div>?

Tags: html, css

I have a little block with text and link image, but don't know how to place it top of `b`

```
        <div class="icon-block">
            <a href="#" class="icon"></a>
            <b>Lorem ipsum</b>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse fringilla.</p>
        </div>

.icon{
background: url(../img/icon.png) top no-repeat;
padding: 30px;
margin: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
.icon{
background: url(../img/icon.png) top no-repeat;
padding: 30px;
margin: 20px;
z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: I found other strange way to put it on top... :ь Just put display:flex; in <a> and it worked lol